# Google Slides - using api a post in a web link

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-slides

Is there a way to "Publish to the Web..." a Google Slides presentation programmatically?

Unlike Sheets, Slides takes in additional parameters for publishing. I am trying to figure out how to push the presentation programmatically and get the published URL

Any help is greatly appreciated.

`   presentation = service.presentations().get(
presentationId=presentation_id
).execute()
print(presentation)

```
# print(presentation)
patched_revision = {
    'published': True,
    'publishAuto': True,
    'publishedOutsideDomain': True
}
resq = service.permissions().update(
    fileId=id_present,
    body=patched_revision
).execute()`

presentation = service.presentations().get(
    presentationId=presentation_id
).execute()
print(presentation)

# print(presentation)
patched_revision = {
    'published': True,
    'publishAuto': True,
    'publishedOutsideDomain': True
}
resq = service.permissions().update(
    fileId=id_present,
    body=patched_revision
).execute()`



permission = {
    'role': 'reader',
    'type': 'anyone',
    'withLink': True
}
```

and with such parameters also tried

I want the presentation to be available at the link
"https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{{ID-PRESENT}}/pub"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds) # Please use your client.

id_present = "###" # Please set your file ID of Google Slide.

service.revisions().update(fileId=id_present, body={"published": True, "publishedOutsideDomain": True, "publishAuto": True}, revisionId=1).execute()
url = f'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{id_present}/pub'
print(url)
```

- When this script is run, `url` can be accessed as the Web-published Google Slide.

#### Reference:

- [Method: revisions.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/revisions/update)

Comment: It's a miracle, I was looking for how to do it all day yesterday. There was even something similar, as you suggest.
But you are my savior. Thank you so much !

Comment: @In Yan Developer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.